# Imagine a Sudoku with Text-Only: A Gridless 6x6 Antiknight Antidouble Sudoku

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, sudoku

Imagine the following Sudoku:

- Imagine the Sudoku has a 6x6 grid with standard boxes, 2 rows and 3 columns each; and standard digits, 1 to 6.
- Imagine it has an antiknight rule: identical digits cannot be chess knight move away from each other.
- Imagine it has an antidouble rule: no digit is orthogonally adjacent to its double.
- Imagine the top-leftmost and bottom-rightmost digits are equal, so do the top-rightmost and bottom-leftmost.
- Imagine in Row 5, there exist 3 adjacent digits that are numerically adjacent too in increasing order from left to right.
- Imagine in Column 1, there exist 3 adjacent digits that are numerically adjacent too in increasing order from top to bottom.

Can you imagine that?

---

<sup>(P.S. This can be fully done logically but might need some "special" knowledge.)</sup>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First step (some simple logical deduction):

> [image]

Now, if we focus on this highlighted 2x3 grid:

> [image] we see two B's. If we choose the red B we would go against the antiknight-rule in the 2x3 grid below the yellow one, so we now know we have to choose the blue B.

That leads to:

> [image] This red B. And the rest of the boxes highlighted in yellow will follow.

Let's clean this up:

> [image]

Now, using some more logic, we can place:

> [image] This red D. And the rest of the highlighted yellow boxes will follow.

Let's clean up again:

> [image] We now have the whole grid in terms of letters. Time to look how we can translate these to numbers, 1-6, using the rules.

From the information given by the rules we can conclude that:

> Column1 and row5 must be of the form, **2-3-4**, **3-4-5** or **4-5-6**
> (note that the possibility 1-2-3 is excluded since 2 is 1 doubled) where its possbible along the column/row. We can see that the string of numbers must include a 4.
> Let's compare column1 possibilities with the corresponding letter-position in row5 and see what happens:

> A-D-C:
>  [image] This string won't work since it's impossible to form a 3 digit consecutive string in row 5.

> D-C-B:
>  [image] Like-wise this string won't work since it's impossible to form a 3 digit consecutive string in row 5.

> C-B-E:
>  Now this one is possible if we choose them to be 3-4-5. The other possibilities (2-3-4 and 4-5-6) don't work.
>  [image]

> Lastly, B-E-F:
>  [image] Same as the two first possibilities we can see that this is impossible.

> This means that the third possibility, **C-B-E**, is the only one that works.

We now replace the letters with the corresponding numbers and get the full grid:

> [image]

Comment: In the first step, why isn't D an option for the first row last column?

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out: top-rightmost and bottom-leftmost are equal.

Comment: Great job and well-explained! I'm giving this a tickmark as it's easier to follow. This is just for an additional info: I mentioned about a "special" knowledge. This knowledge is actually regarding an antiknight 6x6 Sudoku: you can paint them in checkerboard then each color will only have 3 distinct numbers each. Using this knowledge, it will speed up a bit to fill the variables and to know which sequence is okay for Row 5 and Column 1. But yours work pretty well too! :D

Comment: @athin Thanks! And nice puzzle :)

Answer (score 8):

The answer is

> Yes, I can imagine it.
>
>
>  [image]

The first step was

> to use the fact that opposite corners were identical digits and that there was an antiknight restriction. This gave me the following:
>
>   [image]
>
>
>  The opposite corner digits can only propogate in the grid in two ways. In the above, only the yellow has been shown in both configurations.

The next step was

> to realize that the most restricted digit is the 4. There are two digits it cannot be adjacent to and it must be part of any 3 digit sequence. I therefore decided to find where the 4 could be in the first column, starting at the bottom:
>
>  [image]
>  In the first configuration, the placement of the 3 and 4 in row 5 means no 3-digit sequence is possible. In the other configuration, the 1 and the 2 are forced to be adjacent. Conclusion: the 4 cannot be at the bottom.

Moving along,

> I tried the 4 in the 5th row, first using a 2-3-4 sequence:
>
>  [image]
>
>  Again, this was not possible as shown. I then tried a 3-4-5 sequence:
>
>   [image]
>   This too is impossible (no matter the yellow configuration) as the 4 can only be part of a 4-5-6 sequence and the 5 is too far away.

Moving up

> I tried the 4 in the 4th row, first using a 2-3-4 sequence:
>   [image]
>  Didn't work in either yellow configuration as no 3-digit sequence could be formed in the 5th row.

And finally

> I tried the sequence 3-4-5 which gave
>
>   [image]
>
>  I.e. the second yellow configuration **worked!**

Nice puzzle! If there is an easier method, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: I know you answered before me, but wanted to show my solving method since I worked on it quite a lot today!

Comment: Well done! An "easier" method to avoid some case bashing has been done by @Prim3numbah: you can actually put all the variables first on the grid and see the only substring that can be for Row 5 and Column 1. :D